# kustomize: inherit labels from base on overlay generator

Tags: kustomize

I don't know how to handle it.

My service is deployed into 3 environments: `des`, `pre` and `pro`.

I only need to generate secret on `des` environment.

On `pre` and `pro` it's deployed by customer devops team.

My `base/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

configurations:
  - kustomizeconfig/configurations/references-configuration.yaml

transformers:
  - kustomizeconfig/transformers/labels-transformer.yaml

generators:
  - kustomizeconfig/generators/configmap-generator.yaml

resources:
  - resources/deployment.yaml
  - resources/service.yaml
```

As you can see, I've created a `labels-transformer.yaml` where I put all my common labels:

```yaml
apiVersion: builtin
kind: LabelTransformer
metadata:
  name: notImportantHere
labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/component: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
fieldSpecs:
- kind: Service
  path: metadata/labels
  create: true
- kind: Service
  path: spec/selector
  create: true
- kind: DeploymentConfig
  path: metadata/labels
  create: true
- kind: DeploymentConfig
  path: spec/template/metadata/labels
  create: true
- kind: ConfigMap
  path: metadata/labels
  create: true
- kind: Secret
  path: metadata/labels
  create: true
```

Into my `des` overlay I'm using a `secret-generator` in order to create the secret.

`kustomize/overlays/des/kustomization.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

transformers:
  # - kustomizeconfig/transformers/name-transformer.yaml
  - kustomizeconfig/transformers/labels-transformer.yaml
  - kustomizeconfig/transformers/image-transformer.yaml

generators:
  - kustomizeconfig/generators/config-generator.yaml
  - kustomizeconfig/generators/secret-generator.yaml

resources:
  - ../../base
```

`kustomize/overlays/des/kustomizeconfig/generators/secret-generator.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: builtin
kind: SecretGenerator
metadata:
    name: security-pwd
envs:
    - env/secret.env
```

However, my secret doesn't inherit labels from base:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  XXX:YYY
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    stage: development
  name: security-pwd-7g4h45kbc8
type: Opaque
```

As you can see, generated secret has only `stage:development` label.

My question, how should I address it?

Remember that secret is always needed, nevertheless, on `pre` and `pro` is externally provided. I mean, I can't put an empty generator on `base` layer since, I don't need to provide it on `pre` and `pro`. Only on `des`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With kustomize, nothing is "inherited". Transformations are only applied to manifests generated by the `kustomization.yaml` that defines the transformations. If you want a set of common labels applied to *all* your resources, you need to set those labels in the "outermost" `kustomization.yaml`.

If you need the same set of labels in multiple overlays and you want to avoid repeating yourself, you can bundle them into a [`component`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/components.md).

### Directory layout

For this example, my directory layout look like:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
├── components
│   └── common-labels
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│       └── labels-transformer.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── des
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── pro
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

### Base configuration

In `components/common-labels/kustomization.yaml` I have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

transformers:
  - labels-transformer.yaml
```

And in `components/common-labels/labels-transformer.yaml` I have the example from your question.

In `base/kustomization.yaml` I have a `kustomization.yaml` that generates a deploymentconfig, a service, and a configmap:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - deployment.yaml
  - service.yaml

configMapGenerator:
  - name: example
    literals:
      - name=alice
      - email=alice@example.com

components:
  - ../components/common-labels
```

Running `kustomize build base` from the top level will generate manifests that have your common labels applied in all the locations specified by your transformer configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  email: alice@example.com
  name: alice
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
    app.kubernetes.io/name: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
  name: example-b5hhtcf222
---
[...]
```

### Overlay configuration

In `overlays/des/kustomization.yaml`, I have:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base

components:
- ../../components/common-labels

secretGenerator:
  - name: security-pwd
    literals:
      - password=secret
```

This outputs the same content as `kustomize build base` with the addition of a Secret resource, which is also appropriately labelled:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: c2VjcmV0
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kustomize
    app.kubernetes.io/name: security-pwd
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: espaidoc
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
  name: security-pwd-m4d885dchh
type: Opaque
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but openshift [recommends using native Deployment resources rather than OpenShift-specific DeploymentConfig resources](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/applications/deployments/what-deployments-are.html):

> Both Kubernetes Deployment objects and OpenShift Container Platform-provided DeploymentConfig objects are supported in OpenShift Container Platform; however, it is recommended to use Deployment objects unless you need a specific feature or behavior provided by DeploymentConfig objects.

If you use `Deployment` objects, you don't need a `LabelsTransformer` configuration (because kustomize knows where to apply labels on a Deployment object); you can just use the `commonLabels` directive in your `kustomization.yaml`.

---

You can find all the code shown in this answer in [this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76671610-common-labels).